# How to take care of my mental health while preparing to leave

Tags: germany

This question will of course get closed as too broad, but I hope I will get a few responses before that. In fact, I hope you guys to hold on a little bit before closing this before I would really appreciate some answers.

Long story short, I'm a soon-to-be expat and I'm scared. My situation is not that bad: I have friends, and I'm leaving with my boyfriend, not alone.

But I would very, very much appreciate some advice regarding how to deal with the anxiety, the fear, the sadness of leaving most of the people I love behind. Thanks.

Comment: How far away are you moving? Is it feasible to make plans for a visit home, or for some friends/family to come visit you? Will it be easy to stay in touch via internet calls, if not what can you do to plan for that?

Comment: "nothing will enable thee to meet death with equanimity better than to observe the environment thou art leaving and the sort of characters with whom thy soul shall no longer be mixed up." (Marcus Aurelius, _Communings_, Book IX.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be better on Interpersonal Skills (not sure though).  Alternatively, it just might not be that suitable for SE.  It would probably help to indicate whereabouts in Germany you are going (Berlin is not the same as the rural Black Forest), where you are from (Netherlands is obviously different to Vietnam) and what your level of competency in German is.